# Exception Handling In Android from Web API

Tags: java, c#, android, asp.net-web-api2, okhttp

My code in MVC API C# this:

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("api/ServiceV1/Test")]
    public IHttpActionResult Test()
    {
        return BadRequest("Catch this message in Android application");
    }
```

Result in PostMan

```
{
    "Message": "Catch this message in Android application"
}
```

I catch this error message on android application. I used okhttp3.

```
    String MIME_JSON = "application/json";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(MIME_JSON), gson.toJson(object));

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(baseUrl + route)
            .post(body)
            .build();

    okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
```

How do to catch this message on the Android application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can read this error:

```
Response response=okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
if (response.code() != 200) {
  errorMessage= response.body().string();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the `Call.execute()` method returns a `Response` object, which has the `code()` method to find the status code, and the `isSuccessful()` method to find whether the code is in the [200,300) range, which generally represent success.

Generally looking at the documentation of libraries you are working with is helpful. [Here's the documentation for okhttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/)